# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mininet'

Tags: python, linux, networking, virtual-machine, mininet

I have installed mininet on my computer and now I want to run a python script with mininet. How should I do so?

If I just use `python3 star.py`, I get an error that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "star.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mininet.cli import CLI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mininet'
```

If I try `sudo mn python3 star.py`, then I get

```
Usage: mn [options]
(type mn -h for details)

The mn utility creates Mininet network from the command line. It can create
parametrized topologies, invoke the Mininet CLI, and run tests.

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

and if I try `sudo mn` and then `python star.py`, that doesnt work either.

Comment: I don't need to run miniedit. I just need to run a python script on mininet. Miniedit is different. @Karthik

Comment: I never run mininet before but if you want to run commands in CLI then you can put them in file - ie. `my_commands.txt` - and redirect `su mn < my_commands.txt`

Comment: I can't `import mininet` in `Python 3` but it works in `Python 2`. It seems it installed module in `Python 2` but not in `Python 3`

Answer (score 2):

Try to download the Mininet code, and export the path.

Example:

```
sudo -i
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/mininet
python3 star.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You might still need to do `pip install mininet` even if you had installed Mininet using the procedure in the [documentation](http://mininet.org/download/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).